# Discord bot not recognizing messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm new to creating bots and I wanted to try and make a bot that would greet me when I said hi and say goodbye when I said bye.

When I activated it, it seemed to not be able to recognize that I sent a message

I checked permissions and it should be able to see it but it doesn't look like it can

here's the code

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We are {0.user} and we are on a cruise".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_messsage(message):
  username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
  user_message = str(message.content)
  channel = str(message.channel.name)
  print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  if channel == 'general':
     if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
      await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
      return
     elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
      await message.channel.send(f'Bye {username}')
      return

client.run(os.environ['taisho-secret'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if channel == 'general':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f'Bye {username}')
            return
```

your problem is that you wrote `on_messsage` and its `on_message`